# showing results obtained after $_POST in a new page

Tags: php, html, forms, post, mysqli

I have been trying to work this out for a while.
I have created a form with a dropdown box that gets results from a database. from this i then `$_POST` that from to another page. From that second page i wish to get the ID number and then get the records and display them on screen.
I will then put them in a table to organise the results better.
can anyone help me in achieving this.

Here is the code for the form (which works and sends the $PlantID)

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM PLANTS";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());

//********************* Botannical name drop down box

echo "<form name='selection' id='selection' action='profile.php' method='post'>";

echo "<select name='flower'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $plantid = $row['FlowerID'];
    $plantname = $row['Botannical_Name'];
    $plantcommon = $row['Common_Name'];
   /* $plantheight = $row['Height'];
    $plantav = $row['AV'];
    $plantcolours = $row['Colours'];
    $plantflowering = $row['Flower_Time'];
    $plantspecial = $row['Special_Conditions'];
    $plantfrost = $row['Frost_Hardy'];
    $plantaspect = $row['Aspect'];
    $plantspeed = $row['Growth_Speed'];*/

    echo "<option value=".$plantid.">".$plantname." -> AKA -> ".$plantcommon."</option>";
} 
echo "</select>";
echo "<br />";


//********************* End of form
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>";
echo "</form>";
```

I have created this page to get the ID and display that ID on screen. AS you can tell i have probably doubled up on ways to try work this out.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM PLANTS";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$selected_val = $_POST['Botannical_Name'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value
}
echo "<br />";
echo "well:".$_POST["Botannical_Name"]."<br/>";
echo "now:".$plantquery."<br />";
echo $_POST;



echo "<table>";
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $key;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? By the looks of it your code should run fine (I even tested it myself using mock data for the $_POST array), what isn't working for you..?

Comment: I am trying to get all the data from the database for the field that the user selects, and then displaying that data as seperate entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use following to get the selected value,

```
$selected_val = $_POST['flower'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $selected_val = $_POST['flower'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
     echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val;  // Displaying Selected Value
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM PLANTS WHERE FlowerID='.$selected_val.'";

     $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());
     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
     {
         echo $row['Botannical_Name'];
     }
}
echo "<br />";
print_r($_POST);


if(!empty(_POST)) {
echo "<table>";
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $key;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</table>";
}
```